# Datagridview two column link shall point to different events

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in a winform with dataset/SQL database. The datagridview has a column with links pointing to websites which is working fine with this event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkColumn)
        {
            Process.Start(this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I need now to add a new link column that contains fileNames of pictures in a local folder.
Due to the above method structure, there is no difference in the behavior of the linkClick event but I need one columnlink to open the URL on click and the other columnLink to open a local file.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got access to the `ColumnIndex` ... you could just check to which column the currently clicked cell belongs to:

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkColumn)
{
    var location = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value);

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        Process.Start(location);
    else if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        // Open the file specified in 'location'
}
```